# Remove Toolbar as actionbar after using setSupportActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I have a toolbar that was set up using setSupportActionBar();, so at some point i want the toolbar not to be the actionbar again.
So is there anyway you can remove a toolbar as actionbar after setting it up using setSupportActionBar.

Comment: `is there anyway you can remove a toolbar as actionbar after setting it up using setSupportActionBar` No. Don't use `setSupportActionBar` and manage `Toolbar` yourself.

Comment: I would want to use setSupportActionBar so as to allow the toolbar have default actionBar properties like navigation and menu.

Comment: That's what `setSupportActionBar` for. You can't call it twice. Manage your toolbars yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Then just try hiding the toolbar view when it is not needed...

Comment: It is still going to be needed but not as an actionBar